# Can I create cloud SQL MySQL instance from Android Application

Tags: android, mysql, google-cloud-platform

I want a new Cloud SQL instance for each user. Is it possible to create a new Cloud SQL instance via an http request or any other means. Right now I am creating it using Google Cloud Platform console.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better call available for the Cloud SQL API which is [insert](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/insert) that basically creates a new instance.

You will probably also want to update the root password and get the IPv4 address of the instance. Instructions on creating a Cloud SQL instance can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance). Go to the CURL(2ND GEN/1ST GEN) section so that you could see what kind of information you need to include in the POST request that you can send from your Android application.

Answer (score -1):

The Cloud SQL API has a clone call which will make a new instance that is a clone of an existing instance.

See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/clone